# react with react-loadable not rendering async pages during SSR

Tags: reactjs, express, react-loadable

I'm creating a new project that incorporates react SSR with react-loadable. (based on https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable/tree/master/example)

The react-loadable docs mention that I need to add "Loadable.preloadAll()" to make sure that the SSR waits for the async components to be rendered. When I open the page source for the SSR, there is no async component and no loading component.

After bootstrapping in the browser, the async component is rendered.

The github:

https://github.com/Exomnius/spearhead/blob/master/packages/web/server/server.jsx

```
Loadable.preloadAll().then(() => {
  app.listen(3000, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }

    if (__DEV__) {
      console.info('==>   Open http://%s:%s in a browser to view the app.', 'localhost', 3000);
    }
  });
});
```

Anyone has experience with this issue? Of am I missing a config?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a way around?

Comment: No, I have no solution yet